# Надписи накладываются друг на друга

Tags: python, kivy

Есть решение ещё проще, вкратце: 'Если виджета нет на экране, это не значит, что он не существует'. Удаленный виджет с экрана все еще есть в памяти и его можно использовать сколько угодно раз

```
# добавление конвертера в избранное
def add_to_star(self, x):

    # окно, на котором находится пользователь
    now_screen = self.sm.current

    # список названий экранов в менеджере экранов
    list_of_screens = list(map(str, self.sm.screens))

    # индекс окна
    index_window = list_of_screens.index(f"<Screen name='{self.sm.current}'>")

    # добавление в избранное конвертера и удаление оттуда же
    if self.menu_items_dots[1]['left_icon'] == 'star-check-outline':

        # меняем значок 'зведздочки белой' на 'звездочку черную'
        self.menu_items_dots[1]['left_icon'] = 'star-check'

        # конвертер добавился, значит увеличиваем значение
        WindowCreateMain.count_of_stars += 1

        # удаление надписи 'Пусто', когда добавляется избранный конвертер
        self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_layout.remove_widget(self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_btn)
        self.sm.screens[1].ids.box_star.remove_widget(self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_layout)

        # создание элемента списка в Избранном для доступа к соответствующему конвертеру
        self.new_star = CheckMark(
            text=self.sm.screens[index_window].ids.title_text.title,
            left_icon='star',
            on_release=lambda x: self.move_to_window(x, now_screen),
        )
        self.sm.screens[1].ids.list_star.add_widget(self.new_star)

        Snackbar(text='Добавлено в избранное').open()
    else:
        # меняем значок 'зведздочки черной' на 'звездочку белую'
        self.menu_items_dots[1]['left_icon'] = 'star-check-outline'
        # удаление элемента из избранного
        self.sm.screens[1].ids.list_star.remove_widget(self.new_star)
        # конвертер удалился, значит уменьшаем значение
        WindowCreateMain.count_of_stars -= 1

        if WindowCreateMain.count_of_stars == 0:
            # добавили виджеты
            self.sm.screens[1].ids.box_star.add_widget(self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_layout)
            self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_layout.add_widget(self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_btn)

        Snackbar(text='Удалено из избранного').open()
    self.menu_dots.dismiss()
```

kv-файл:
:
list_star: list_star
box_star: box_star
empty_layout: empty_layout.**self**
empty_btn: empty_btn.**self**
MDBoxLayout:
id: box_star
orientation: 'vertical'
MDToolbar:
title: 'Избранное'
left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda x: app.back()]]
right_action_items: [['dots-vertical']]
ScrollView:
MDList:
id: list_star
MDFloatLayout:
id: empty_layout
MDTextButton:
id: empty_btn
text:
'''Странно, ничего нет,
нажмите сюда и перейдите на главный экран,
чтобы добавить что-нибудь в "Избранное"'''
font_size: 16
pos: 60, 350
size: 380, 50
on_release:
app.root.current = 'choose'
root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первый раз ты убираешь надпись 'Пусто' из kv-файла, а во второй раз ты пытаешься убрать сгенерированные виджеты из функции, однако при каждом новом вызове функции add_star появляется новая кнопка и новый лайаут с новыми айди, поэтому удаляться они не будут. Нужно заготовить их для дальнейшего использования в инициализации класса-окна, чтобы каждый раз айди кнопки и лайаута не менялись, т. е. будет одна кнопка и один лайаут при создании этого окна

```
# динамически созданная надпись 'Пусто'
    self.btn_empty_din = MDTextButton(
        text='Странно, ничего нет,\nнажмите сюда и перейдите на главный экран,\nчтобы добавить что-нибудь в "Избранное"',
        font_size=6,
        pos=(60, 350),
        on_release=lambda x: self.move_to_window(x, 'choose', 'right')
    )
    # динамически созданная разметка
    self.empty_layout_din = MDFloatLayout()
# добавление конвертера в избранное
def add_to_star(self, x):

    # окно, на котором находится пользователь
    now_screen = self.sm.current

    # список названий экранов в менеджере экранов
    list_of_screens = list(map(str, self.sm.screens))

    # индекс окна
    index_window = list_of_screens.index(f"<Screen name='{self.sm.current}'>")
    print(self.btn_empty_din)

    # добавление в избранное конвертера и удаление оттуда же
    if self.menu_items_dots[1]['left_icon'] == 'star-check-outline':

        # меняем значок 'зведздочки белой' на 'звездочку черную'
        self.menu_items_dots[1]['left_icon'] = 'star-check'

        # конвертер добавился, значит увеличиваем значение
        WindowCreateMain.count_of_stars += 1

        # удаление надписи 'Пусто', когда добавляется избранный конвертер
self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_layout.remove_widget(self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_btn)
        self.sm.screens[1].ids.box_star.remove_widget(self.sm.screens[1].ids.empty_layout)
        # удаление виджетов из самой инициализации
        self.empty_layout_din.remove_widget(self.btn_empty_din)
        self.sm.screens[1].ids.box_star.remove_widget(self.empty_layout_din)

        # создание элемента списка в Избранном для доступа к соответствующему конвертеру
        self.new_star = CheckMark(
            text=self.sm.screens[index_window].ids.title_text.title,
            left_icon='star',
            on_release=lambda x: self.move_to_window(x, now_screen),
        )
        self.sm.screens[1].ids.list_star.add_widget(self.new_star)

        Snackbar(text='Добавлено в избранное').open()
    else:
        # меняем значок 'звездочки черной' на 'звездочку белую'
        self.menu_items_dots[1]['left_icon'] = 'star-check-outline'
        # удаление элемента из избранного
        self.sm.screens[1].ids.list_star.remove_widget(self.new_star)
        # конвертер удалился, значит уменьшаем значение
        WindowCreateMain.count_of_stars -= 1

        if WindowCreateMain.count_of_stars == 0:
            # добавили виджеты
            self.empty_layout_din.add_widget(self.btn_empty_din)
            self.sm.screens[1].ids.box_star.add_widget(self.empty_layout_din)

        Snackbar(text='Удалено из избранного').open()
    self.menu_dots.dismiss()
```

Comment: блин, ответ не туда добавил